# Code equivalent for State-Space Simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink, state-space

I am currently working on Simulink/Matlab code the idea is to remove some Simulink blocks that annoy our developing team. We are fighting with [State-Space Model](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/statespace.html?searchHighlight=state%20space&s_tid=doc_srchtitle). The configuration of mentioned block is presented as follows:

[image: Configuration of State-Space Station]

Our question is: **Is there any way to rewrite this using pure Matlab scripts functions?** We were trying some approaches with `idss` and `ss` models but so far we failed. We are not Matlab experts. This is the pseudo-code that we with will solve the problem, but we are not an experts in maths.

`ss(A, B, C, D); 
[y, t, x] = initial(tmp, x0);`

Comment: You can model it manually with built-in derivative, product, sum and constant blocks and matlab function blocks with your own code.

Comment: @Sairus Can you provide some additional informations about it, some simplified examples?

Comment: What you want is using the matlab-function block to replace the state-space block, right? the matlab-function block would need to solve the differential equation dx/dt=Ax+Bu. Solving that yields x(t) which you can use to calculate your y(t) which is the output. If you provide some example data for u(t) , A, B, C and D, I could try solving this issue for you.

Comment: @Max Unfortunately I cannot give you this example data, because it very big chunk of data. Although I would very appreciate the help inline 'ss(A, B, C, D); [y, t, x] = initial(tmp, x0);'

Comment: Sorry, I'm not experienced with this kind of stuff either. I think if I had example data, I could figure it out, but I can't help you with this.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to overcome in writing your own block rather than using the built-in block?  There are multiple ways the block could be "re-implemented" but I can't see how any of them are easier than just using the block itself.

Comment: Well, the problem is that we have a series of those blocks which could be executed in parallel. The idea is to write a Matlab code to use it inside parfor loop. Do you know any implementations of this problem?

Comment: So within a single simulation/model, at every time step, you want to run a parfor loop to execute some parts of the model in parallel?